# Google Maps API V2 - Can't see module folder

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to integrate google maps API v2 into my project.

My build dependency is:

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

I've downloaded the android google play services and the google repository.

However, when i actually try to import the maps module the only directory that's displayed is:

```
import com.google.android.gms.R;
```

What's the reason for this? How can i import `import com.google.android.gms.maps`?

Comment: The answer was to add dependencies for the older library version of 3.1.36 irritatingly.

   ` dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the versions for support and google play services you are using are available in your Android SDK under directory

For Support

```
  $SDK_DIR\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4
```

For Google Play Services

```
  $SDK_DIR\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

**In case you are using Android Studio 0.4.2 do upgrade it to 0.4.3 because there were some dependency related issues in 0.4.2.**